# GoPro Hero battery replacement

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, camera, drone

I am attempting to power my GoPro Hero 10 from a 1S2P 3.7 V Li-ion battery (2x18650s in parallel, from Tenergy Power): https://power.tenergy.com/AT-3.6V-7000mAh-Li-Ion-Pack-34041_1/?gad=1&gclid=CjwKCAiAxreqBhAxEiwAfGfndOGGFLDVyp7z98KBOFe4Pl0Wlr9-j5StotUD4C4fHGIxb5AzgVwGyRoCibUQAvD_BwE

This is for a space and weight constrained project (not a drone, so no auxiliary Li-ion Pouch cells available onboard). I am hoping to use this battery as a drop-in replacement for the stock GoPro battery, which is also 3.7 V (measured with a multimeter), but with ~4x the capacity.

The problem is simple: when I plug in the stock four-lead Li-ion battery, the camera boots up and all is fine. But when I plug in the 2-lead Li-ion battery, the camera does nothing. I am wondering if anybody knows what the other two leads on the four-lead battery wire are? Do they communicate with the battery PCB or a thermistor?

In the attached images, I show the connections I am making for both the stock Li-ion battery holder and the modified connector for the replacement Li-ion battery. As a sanity check, I'm including pictures of the voltmeter output showing that the voltage (measured at the terminals of the white connector) are equal for both batteries.

Note that the GoPro battery wire color convention is odd -- blue is positive but red is negative. Any help would be appreciated. Images are here: https://imgur.com/a/Gt39wVX. Note that I am tagging "drone" because these mods are often performed by drone racers/FPV folks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the main board is communicating with the BMS on board of the original battery. If it can't, it doesn't run.

Alternatively, it's because the main board is reading the temperature of the original battery through an integral thermistor. If it can't, it doesn't run.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, all! I tried the method in the linked video and it worked. I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a BMS in the cell. You (apparently) can combine a donor cell's BMS and an external battery. Do a web search, this is not an uncommon request. For example, [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=89XbFMRjf1g) video. I don't know if his method is okay or not.

You may also be able to use the USB-C connector directly with a power bank. Some USB-C cables now (somehow) have a 6A rating and you may need a well-made cable for it to work directly.